# Unit of output changes when constant quantity is moved over integral

Tags: bugs, units

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

*`Quantity` is new in 9.0.*

---

Why do these two expressions give the same result in different units?
In:

```
Integrate[
 gravitationalAcceleration  Quantity[1, "g/m^3"] fluidArea h, {h, 0, height}]
```

Out:

```
Quantity[1/2 fluidArea gravitationalAcceleration height^2, 
 "Grams" "Meters"]
```

In:

```
Quantity[1, "g/m^3"] Integrate[
  gravitationalAcceleration  fluidArea h, {h, 0, height}]
```

Out:

```
fluidArea gravitationalAcceleration height^2 (Quantity[1/2, (
   "Grams")/("Meters")^3])
```

Comment: I think we can safely use the `BUG` tag here.  In the spirit of minimal working examples, this is wrong too `Integrate[  x Quantity[1, "Meters^2"]  p , {p, 0, z}]`  ( V10.1 )